# what's the best way, using the TFS API, to add a label to a file?

Tags: tfs

I'd like to add a label to a set of files using the TFS API. My code looks like this:

```
VersionControlLabel label = new VersionControlLabel(this.vcServer, this.label,
                this.vcServer.AuthenticatedUser, this.labelScopeDirectory, this.labelComment);

            List<LabelItemSpec> labelSpecs = new List<LabelItemSpec>();

            // iterate files and versions 
            foreach (var fileAndVersion in this.filesAndVersions)
            {
                VersionSpec vs = null;
                Item i = null;
                // i have no idea why the itemspec is needed instead of the item and version... 
                ItemSpec iSpec = new ItemSpec("{0}/{1}".FormatString(this.source, fileAndVersion.Key), RecursionType.None);
                GetItemAndVersionSpec(fileAndVersion.Key, fileAndVersion.Value, out vs, out i);
                labelSpecs.Add(new LabelItemSpec(iSpec, vs, false));
            }

            this.vcServer.CreateLabel(label, labelSpecs.ToArray(), LabelChildOption.Merge);
```

(there are some extension methods in there... this is all largely lifted from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/archive/2006/08/08/692281.aspx))

The thing that concerns me is things like this in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.labelchildoption%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
This enumeration supports the .NET Framework infrastructure 
and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
```

So MSDN is telling me not to use that enumeration (LabelChildOption), which is afaik the only way to create a label and add it to a file.

Is there a better way? Is this sort of a "grey" area in the TFS API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // i have no idea why the itemspec is needed instead of the item and version...

ItemSpec contains a RecursionType.  If you know in advance you're going to be labeling all children of a folder (either 1-level, or with full recursion into all subfolders), you can use an ItemSpec to greatly condense the size of the LabelItemSpec[] that will be passed to & from the server.

> Is this sort of a "grey" area in the TFS API?

Not grey, just poorly documented.  Labels are kind of an afterthought in TFS; they play no role in the "Microsoft way" of managing a SDLC, and so you won't find them mentioned in the guidance at all.  From what I can tell, they're mostly there for feature completeness (aka competitive analysis).  They are also handy for several complex one-off database manipulations that would otherwise not be possible from the client API.

Read Buck Hodges' explanation in the "community content" section below the MSDN article -- that's the important part.  Replace is generally closer to what people want than Merge, but if you're certain you're creating a brand new label then it doesn't matter.